# How old was Han Solo when Luke and Leia were born?

Tags: star-wars, han-solo

We all know that Han Solo is several years older than Luke; he always calls Luke 'kid', and Luke was just being born in the end of *Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith*.

**How old was Han Solo when Luke and Leia were born?**

---

<sub>Bonus question: If he's old enough, does Han appear in any of the prequel trilogy films?</sub>

Comment: You might want to check your recent posts for edits made to them as they all have pretty much had an edit and all for the same reasons. Look why they were edited and try and improve next time. A couple of main things, focus on using capitalisation correctly and look at the tags you are using, for example, you always need the franchise tag, [[tag:star-wars]], for Star Wars questions and not really individual film tags most of the time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [Han Solo on Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Han_Solo#Early_life)

> Han was born on the planet Corellia during the waning years of the Galactic Republic around 32 BBY

From [Luke Skywalker on Wookieepedia](http://The%20son%20of%20Jedi%20Knight%20Anakin%20Skywalker%20and%20Senator%20Padm%C3%A9%20Amidala,%20Luke%20Skywalker%20was%20born%20along%20with%20his%20twin%20sister,%20Leia,%20in%2019%20BBY.)

> The son of Jedi Knight Anakin Skywalker and Senator Padmé Amidala,
> Luke Skywalker was born along with his twin sister, Leia, in 19 BBY.

Which puts Han at about 13 years old when Luke and Leia were born.

Han was still on Corellia at this point, and as far as we know hadn't been off planet by then. None of the action around the prequels occurs on Corellia, so that's why we don't see Han in any of the prequel movies.

Comment: Not very surprisingly, that's close to the age difference between the actors, Harrison Ford and Carrie Fisher.  IIRC, Ford was 29 when Ep. IV was filmed, Fisher was 17 at the start of filming.

Answer (score 6):

**Han was canonically born in 32BBY.**

The canon [*Solo - A Star Wars Story - The Official Guide*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Solo:_A_Star_Wars_Story_The_Official_Guide) gives us a nice timeline of Han's life. We don't have a *precise* birthdate for him, but we can see from the chart that his birth is listed as occurring 13 years before [the Empire was declared](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Declaration_of_a_New_Order) (in 19BBY, the same year that Luke and Leia were born).

> [image: 22 BKR: Estimated date of Han's birth on Corellia; 9 BKR: The Galactic Empire sweeps into power]

This is also backed up in the *[Star Wars: Timelines](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Timelines)* factbook.

> [image]
> <sub>**"32BBY - Han Solo - Born in a rough-and-tumble Favela on Corellia"**</sub>

---

As to whether he appears in the prequel films, the answer is a firm 'no' although Millennium Falcon does cameo in *Revenge of the Sith*.

Han also makes an appearance in [LEGO Star Wars: The Padawan Menace](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/LEGO_Star_Wars:_The_Padawan_Menace), a non-canon story set in the Prequel era.

Answer (score 1):

#### Legends: 10 years old

In the Legends continuity, Han was born in or around 29 BBY, ten years before Luke and Leia. According to a 2005 blog post by Leland Chee, "Keeper of the Holocron" at Lucasfilm:

> #### Major Character Birth Years
>
> List of approximate year of birth for major characters.
>
> -896 Yoda
>
> ~ -600 Jabba the Hutt
>
> ~ -200 Chewbacca
>
> -102 Count Dooku
>
> [...]
>
> **-29 Han Solo**
>
> [...]
>
> -19 Star Wars: Episode III Revenge of the Sith [16:5:23]
>
> **-19 Luke Skywalker & Princess Leia** (Luke born first)
>
> [...]
>
> 0 Star Wars: Episode IV A New Hope
>
> <sub>[Keeper of the Holocron's Blog: Major Character Birth Years](https://web.archive.org/web/20090119212402/https://blogs.starwars.com/holocron/13/comments) (2005-09-13); emphasis added</sub>

While Han doesn't appear in any of the prequels, there were plans at one point for him to appear as a child on Kashyyyk in *Revenge of the Sith*:

> "It's not in the script anymore, but we were told that Han Solo was on Kashyyyk and that he was being raised by Chewbacca. He's such a persnickety guy later on—he always has to have the best of everything—so I thought it'd be great if when he was a kid, he was an absolute slob."
>
> —McCaig
>
> ##### January 10-24, 2003
>
> Lucas asks for a conference room on Kashyyyk—and a costume for a young Han Solo, who is slated to meet Yoda on this planet and actually to help him to locate General Grievous. His one and only costume and character style are approved as soon as they're presented.
>
> <sub>[*The Art of Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Art_of_Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith), page 90</sub>

---

Note that this differs from Han's birthdate in 32 BBY in the later Canon continuity, as covered by the other answers. As far as I know, Han is the only major character to have a different age in Legends vs. Canon. I haven't been able to find when or why this change was made, but it may have been driven by characterization and casting in *Solo: A Star Wars Story*.